# tcsh autocompletion for modulefiles

Tags: autocomplete, tcsh, modulefile

I found this piece of code, which does auto-completion for module files in tcsh at
https://opensource.apple.com/source/tcsh/tcsh-66/tcsh/complete.tcsh.

Could somebody help me understand how the 'alias Compl_module' works?

```
#from Dan Nicolaescu <dann@ics.uci.edu>
if ( $?MODULESHOME ) then
  alias Compl_module 'find ${MODULEPATH:as/:/ /} -name .version -o -name .modulea\* -prune -o -print  | sed `echo "-e s@${MODULEPATH:as%:%/\*@@g -e s@%}/\*@@g"`'
  complete module 'p%1%(add load unload switch display avail use unuse update purge list clear help initadd initrm initswitch initlist initclear)%' \
  'n%{unl*,sw*,inits*}%`echo "$LOADEDMODULES:as/:/ /"`%' \
  'n%{lo*,di*,he*,inita*,initr*}%`eval Compl_module`%' \
  'N%{sw*,initsw*}%`eval Compl_module`%' 'C%-%(-append)%' 'n%{use,unu*,av*}%d%' 'n%-append%d%' \
  'C%[^-]*%`eval Compl_module`%'
endif
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this `Compl_module` alias is performing well as it tries to determine all existing modulefiles in modulepaths by just looking at existing files. Modulefiles can also be aliases, symbolic versions and virtual (in newer Modules versions >=4.1), so the `Compl_module` alias will miss that.

You will find a full completion script for the `module` command [in the source repository of the Modules project](https://github.com/cea-hpc/modules/blob/master/init/tcsh_completion.in).

This completion script calls `module avail` to correctly get all existing modulefiles in enabled modulepaths.

TCSH completion script is automatically enabled starting Modules version 4.0.

Comment: Hi Xavier,
Thanks a lot; upgrading solved the problem!